# Number of hexagonal lattice points inside a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, discrete-geometry

Consider a regular hexagonal lattice, like so

[image]

Given a circle centred at a vertex in this lattice, with radius $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$, is the number of lattice points inside this circle known?

**Note:** The purpose of this question is simply to inquire whether this is a known result, and/or to ask for suggestions on how to approach such a problem.

**Some thoughts:** Over a square lattice, this has been extensively studied, so I wonder if some of the techniques used there could be extended to a hexagonal lattice, where these are fundamentally different problems. This, in a way, is the hexagonal version of the Gauss Circle Problem, which was also [discussed here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109515/the-gauss-circle-problem-on-a-hexagonal-lattice).

Any ideas?

Comment: For the case of polygons (not circles), two keywords come to my mind : "Ehrart polynomials" and "zonotopes". See them applied together in this [Master's thesis](https://matthbeck.github.io/teach/masters/elli.pdf)

Comment: your quest at least is somewhat correlated to the generalized Waterman polytopes, cf. https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/lattice.htm#waterman